Pyspark job on sagemaker using airflow
Our team wants to run a pyspark job using sagemaker compute by airflow. On exploring I came across two ways

sagemakerprocessing operator by airflow
pysparkprocessing class within sagemaker python sdk (would have to be executed using a python operator)

We need to run a pyspark transformation jobs on our dataset and couldn't find much insights on which approach would be better to go with. Mostly I found this is how it can be executed but doesn't explain why to use this. Apart from the fact that sagemakerprocessing operator would provide direct integration with airflow, what else are the factors that could be kept in mind to decide the approach.
Can someone please help with this. Thanks

The SageMaker airflow operator sallows you to build SageMaker jobs directly into airflow:
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/airflow/using_workflow.html
If you already use the SageMaker SDK, you can write the operators in that way you can using the Python Operators.
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/airflow/using_workflow.html#using-airflow-python-operator
The Python Operators flow will give you more ability to customize and flexibility
